# What is the period of the composition of hyperbolic tangent and hyperbolic arcsine?

Tags: periodic-functions, hyperbolic-functions

Consider the following indefinite integral: $ \int \mathrm d s = \tanh \left ( \mathrm {arcsinh} \frac{\beta}{\alpha} \right ) \, $ where $ 0 < \alpha \in \mathbb R \; $ is constant and $ \beta \in \mathbb R \; $ varies . How can I evaluate the period of $ \int \mathrm d s \, $ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hyperbolic functions are not perodic.

But what you have can be simplified.

$y = \sinh x = \frac 12 (e^x - e^{-x})$

let $z = e^{x}$

$2y = z - \frac {1}{z}\\
z^2 - 2yz - 1 = 0\\
z = y\pm \sqrt {y^2+1}\\
x = \arctan y =  \ln z$

If $z = y + \sqrt {y^2+1}$ then $\frac {1}{z} = y - \sqrt {y^2+1}$

$\tanh x = \frac {\sinh x}{\cosh x}\\
\tanh (\text{arcsinh} x) = \frac {x}{\cosh (\text{arcsinh} x)}\\
\tanh (\text{arcsinh} x) = \frac {x}{e^{\text{arcsinh} x} +e^{-\text {arcsinh} x} }\\
\tanh (\text{arcsinh} x) = \frac {x}{z + \frac {1}{z}}\\
\tanh (\text{arcsinh} x) = \frac {x}{\sqrt {x^2+1}}\\
\tanh (\text{arcsinh} \frac {b}{a}) = \frac {b}{\sqrt {a^2+b^2}}\\
$